# Firebase Console is not delivering push notification to my iOS app although they are getting delivered when sent from my Server to the iOS app

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-firestore, apple-push-notifications, firebase-console

Firebase Console is not delivering push notification to my iOS app although they are getting delivered when sent from my Server to the iOS app.

I have setup the Key in console as well and I also tried with new APNS certificates by removing Key but it is not working.

Interestingly they are working fine for my Android app means the notifications are getting delivered when sent from the console or from our Server.

Please let me know if I am missing out on anything.

Comment: Interestingly after updating the expired APNS certificates my iOS app started getting push notifications from Firebase console again. Although it should have worked fine with Key as well. But I believe Firebase Console required valid APNS certificates to send push notifications from its console.

Comment: And they started working a day after I updated the expired APNS certificates.